# How can a student get a mentor?

Tags: research-process, advisor

How can a student get a academic mentor to help during publications and research.

Comment: Are you enrolled at a university?

Comment: @DaveClarke Unfortunately not I am 3 years of being in University.

Comment: @RohanVijjhalwar I didn't quite understand your response. Does that mean you are a high school / secondary school student? Or that you are three years away from starting university or that you finished university three years ago?

Comment: in my opinion, Stack Exchange is full of mentors

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas:

- Ask around for a student assistant job that can yield a first glimpse inside the world of research.
- Write your thesis about one of the topics that you alluded to in your question. This can be a first step towards a paper and it is an opportunity to discuss your topic with a professor.

Comment: this was assuming the OP is enrolled at a university. i keep this answer, because it might be useful for someone who is.

Answer (score 2):

Mentors and advisors serve two different purposes.

An *advisor* is someone who acts in academic or research capacity as a supervisor for teaching or training purposes. A *mentor* acts like a counselor, providing advice about how to conduct one's studies and one's career.

The biggest difference between an advisor and a mentor is the notion of "received benefit"; an advisor has a vested interest in your success (perhaps she will write papers with you if you succeed), while a mentor should have a more altruistic attitude, and should not expect any such benefits from helping you. (They're helping you because they want to see you succeed.)

Someone can be both an advisor and a mentor at the same time, but this is a relatively rare combination (usually it's someone who has already been quite successful, and so further "benefits" from helping you don't make a large dent in his or her career).

As for finding a mentor, this can be a bit tricky; often they start out (temporarily) as an advisor, and then migrate into a mentor role. Sometimes they can be friends or family, or you can be introduced through a mutual colleague. There are also some programs available that help to find mentors for young students. But there's no magic wand that produces mentors out of thin air. You'll have to work at finding one—and keeping one! (And ultimately, *more* than one.)

Comment: I currently want to find someone who has experience in the field to help me out - Is it good if I message few academics from Local Universities? Or would that be too irritating for academics?

Comment: Unless they specifically say on a webpage that they don't want such emails, you're free to write whomever you like. However, they may not be willing to answer. Getting an introduction from a mutual acquaintance would probably work much better.

Comment: The difference between an advisor and a mentor is important and well put in this answer. Getting an advisor probably requires some institutional work, but getting a mentor can be easy. See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=of4jy38uJaM

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you join several of the professional communities associated with information security.  (I assume you mean "information security" when you say "security".)  Get to know people in the community, find people with similar interests, ask questions, and ask for advice and support.  The people who respond positively might be candidates for mentors.

Some communities are formal and some are informal.  Some are centered on a geography and some are not.  Some are focused on physical interaction and others are on-line/virtual.  Depending on where you are located, you may or may not have easy access to some of these options.  The good news is that, in the year 2015, it is easier than ever to connect with professional communities nearly anywhere in the world.

Look for your local chapter of ACM and IEEE.  Look for Meetups and hackathons in your area.  Look for conferences and workshops to attend.  Look for on-line mailing lists on topics that interest you, and then join them.  Join Twitter and start following information security professionals and academics there.

Answer (score -1):

This may depend on the institution where s/he studies, for example:

For schools, these young students can select a teacher who has a postgraduate degree in their subject of interest as their mentor, just as in colleges & universities, the person who supervises a young student during his/her thesis, which is generally written for a postgraduate degree, becomes his/her mentor.